# Protege - OWL/XML Syntax - Why are the "Built in datatypes" Ranges red(unselectable)?

Tags: ontology, protege

I want to add a "string" to the field "Range", for a data property, but they are all unselectable (red), how do I get them to be green?
It is created with "OWL/XML Syntax".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr5ur.png)

Comment: But "OK" isn't disabled, right? "Red" doesn't mean "unselectable".  Go to *Entities > Datatypes*. A lot of red! See https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/blob/v5.2.0/protege-editor-core/src/main/java/org/protege/editor/core/ProtegeApplication.java#L275 (but the default "stub" icon for data ranges is not red; you're correct here)